# Consume soap web service from Azure web app

Tags: web-services, azure, telnet, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to consume a soap web service from an azure web app.

To do this I need to run a connectivity test through telnet to do this.

How would I go about doing this in Azure?

thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Telnet client is not setup by default on Azure App Service.
It is not possible to install it as it requires elevated permissions.

My advice would be to develop a quick app, for example based on this kind of tool: https://github.com/mkozjak/node-telnet-client

Hope this helps,